# Keep built products for various simulators in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to test the same app on two simulators.
I try to build the same target without any changes for two simulators iPhone Xr and iPhone Xs Max and Xcode create fresh builds and takes lot of time whenever I switch the run target from one to another simulator.
Is there any way we can make Xcode keep the built products for various simulators so that whenever I run target is changed to another simulator builds are speed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build once **CMD** + **B**.

[image: Build]

Then Run muiltiple simulator's without building **Ctrl** + **CMD** + **R**

[image: RUN Without Building]